# Using Foreign Keys with different Contexts using Entity Framework code-first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I have a brand-new ASP.NET MVC 5 project with one `DbContext` using Entity Framework 6.1 and Identity 2.2.1. Trying go use IoC, I created a 2nd `DbContext` and some classes belonging to that 2nd context.

Most of these classes have a foreign key to the `IdentityUser` class within Identity 2.2.1. The problem I'm having is that when I try to use `Add-Migrations` I get the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> {MyProjectName}.DataContexts.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> {MyProjectName}.DataContexts.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
>
> IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

When I move the classes I created from my 2nd context into the initial context, I don't get any error and the database table build as expected.

**How can I keep IoC AND have foreign key restrictions work properly with EF and CodeFirst?**

### Sample

You can find a sample project at https://github.com/RoLYroLLs/MultiDbContextForeignKeySample. To recreate the error run this on the Package Manager Console:

```
Enable-Migrations -MigrationsDirectory "DataContexts\ClientMigrations" -ContextTypeName MultiDbContextForeignKeySample.DataContexts.ClientDbContext
```

Comment: @gert-arnold, what makes you think this is a duplicate as the one you marked it as? Did you really read the error I have having? Do you need me to expand my explanation?

Comment: @GertArnold, No problem. Thank you for reopening it. I'm making a sample project for someone to help out easily just in case.

Comment: If you are going to reference Identity's ApplicationUser you either need to configure your classes under a context that inherits from IdentityDbContext as you have seen, or you could just clone a user class in your app context that maps to AspNetUsers and is used for references.

Comment: @SteveGreene since I'm still fairly new to EF/C# can you provide an example on the second method? If you don't mind can you use my sample project and provide a pull request. Thanks.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs did you ever get an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @EschersEnigma I have not.

Comment: Hi @EschersEnigma, I haven't received anything on this. Do you have a possible answer you can provide? Thanks!

Comment: Nope. I actually became so frustrated attempting to do this, I completely dropped the project. It's an absolute nightmare to work with IdentityFramework unless you have someone extremely experienced sitting next to you. I suggest you look at more reasonable frameworks.

Comment: @EschersEnigma, ok thank you for trying. I understand the frustration. =)